# Remove spaces/borders between the rows/columns

Tags: html, css, html-table

Attached is a screenshot of an HTML table that I made. I used some simple css to color the table cells into that withe color... the page background is the blue color that looks like some sort of border between them. How can I remove this border/space between the cells?

[image]

Comment: `table { border-collapse: collapse; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1

```
<table cellspacing="0">
```

Option 2

```
/* CSS */
table {
     border-collapse: collapse;
}
```